# Django: Galleries Admin Photo Upload

Tags: django, file-upload, django-models, django-admin, multiple-file-upload

I have a website that is using Django's admin interface to facilitate non-developers adding content to the site. The site has an Events page (and associated model), and each Event can have an associated photo gallery.

I'm thinking that photo galleries should have their own model. There is a table in the database which associates image paths with their Event.

What I need is a way to upload images. Preferably a multiple-file upload solution since there could be dozens of images per event. I want these images to be recorded correctly in their table and added to the file system in the correct location on the server.

I was originally thinking that the upload feature should be included on the Event admin page to make it easier for content contributors, but maybe it would be easier to keep a separate photo gallery admin and have them select the Event the photos are associated with from there?

I've read through a lot of similar questions and blog posts, but nothing that seems to be quite exactly what I'm looking for. I'm currently attempting to adapt some of the information I've seen, but I'd really appreciate suggestions. Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Some` model with foreign key to Event, and ManyToMany to your Images, as I understand your question.
At first upload necessary images to some Image model and than add them to `Some` model with some Event